# Elastic Logstash JDBC sqlserver insert Existing data again repeatly

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, kibana

I'm using Elastic Logstash to import data from Sql-Server 2016 to elasticsearch.
I'm using this config for logstash :

```html
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\Development\Elastic\elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.1\lib\sqljdbc42.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-92GPVCD;databaseName=Safenat;user=user;password=pass;"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    statement => "SELECT * from Content"
    type => "Content" 
  }
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\Development\Elastic\elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.1\lib\sqljdbc42.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-92GPVCD;databaseName=Safenat;user=user;password=pass;"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    statement => "SELECT * from Tag"
    type => "Tag" 
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "MYINDEX"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

and i use kibana to see what happend . logstash log.txt fast increse size and kibana _cat/indices also show data size increase on in my index
I want to import every record just once . what can i do ?